# Boruvka's algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, greedy, minimum-spanning-tree

```
class Edge
{
public:
    int v1;
    int v2;
    int weight;
};
class Subset
{
public:
    int rank;
    int parent;
};
int find(Subset* subsets,int V)
{
    if(subsets[V].parent!=V)
        subsets[V].parent= find(subsets,subsets[V].parent);
    return subsets[V].parent;
}
void union_rank(Subset* subsets,int x,int y)
{
    if(subsets[x].rank>subsets[y].rank)
        subsets[y].parent=x;
    else   if(subsets[x].rank<subsets[y].rank)
                subsets[x].parent=y;
    else
        {
              subsets[y].parent=x;
              subsets[x].rank++;
        }
}
void boruvka(Edge* list,int V,int E)
{
    Subset* subsets=new Subset[V];
int *cheapest = new int[V];
for(int i=0;i<V;i++)
{
    subsets[i].parent=i;
    subsets[i].rank=0;
     cheapest[V] = -1;
}
    int numTrees = V;
    int MSTweight = 0;
    while (numTrees > 1)
    {
          for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
           {
               cheapest[v] = -1;
           }
        for (int i=0; i<E; i++)
        {
            int x = find(subsets, list[i].v1);
            int y = find(subsets, list[i].v2);
            if (x!=y)
             {
               if (cheapest[x] == -1 || list[cheapest[x]].weight > list[i].weight)
                 cheapest[x] = i;

               if (cheapest[y] == -1 ||list[cheapest[y]].weight > list[i].weight)
                 cheapest[y] = i;
            }
        }
        for (int i=0; i<V; i++)
        {
            if (cheapest[i] != -1)
            {
                int x = find(subsets, list[i].v1);
                int y = find(subsets, list[i].v2);

                if (x==y)
                    continue;
                MSTweight += list[cheapest[i]].weight;
                cout<<list[cheapest[i]].v1<<" "<<list[cheapest[i]].v2<<" "<<list[cheapest[i]].weight<<endl;

                union_rank(subsets, x, y);
                numTrees--;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Weight of MST is %d\n", MSTweight);
    return;
}
int main()
{
int V, E, tempX, tempY,wt;
cin >>V>>E;
Edge* list=new Edge[E];
for(int i=0;i<E;i++)
{
    cin>>tempX>>tempY>>wt;
    list[i].v1=tempX;
    list[i].v2=tempY;
    list[i].weight=wt;
}
//sort(list,list+E,comp);
boruvka(list,V,E);
    return 0;
}
```

My algorithm keeps going into infinite loop for bigger graphs can someone help me resolve it?I worked for ver small graphs but anything similar to this graph it goes into infinite loop.I checked the value of numTree and it stops decreasing after a certain value I'm not sure why.
This is the graph I checked with:

```
14 20
    0 1 1
    0 2 2
    0 7 3
    1 2 4
    1 3 5
    2 5 6
    3 4 7
    3 10 8
    4 5 9
    4 6 10
    5 9 11
    5 12 12
    6 7 13
    7 8 14
    8 9 15
    8 13 16
    10 11 17
    10 13 18
    11 12 19
    12 13 20
```

Comment: Are you sure its the  size of the graph that causes it to fail? Maybe its just that larger graphs have more chance to contain a problematic minor - maybe test it on complete graphs and large cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this for loop

```
        for (int i=0; i<V; i++)
        {
            if (cheapest[i] != -1)
            {
                int x = find(subsets, list[i].v1);
                int y = find(subsets, list[i].v2);

                if (x==y)
                    continue;
                MSTweight += list[cheapest[i]].weight;
                cout<<list[cheapest[i]].v1<<" "<<list[cheapest[i]].v2<<" "<<list[cheapest[i]].weight<<endl;

                union_rank(subsets, x, y);
                numTrees--;
            }
        }
```

You're iterating over the vertices here `i=0..V-1` but you're accessing the list of edges inside the loop `list[i]` which is incorrect.

Instead you should change the for loop to iterate over the edges `i=0..E-1` and change the body of the loop to the following:

```
int x = find(subsets, list[i].v1);
int y = find(subsets, list[i].v2);
if (x==y)
  continue;
if (cheapest[x] == list[i].weight || cheapest[y] == list[i].weight) { // this checks if the given edge is the cheapest from the tree containing x or the tree containing y
  MSTweight += list[cheapest[i]].weight;
  union_rank(subsets, x, y);
  union_rank(subsets, x, y);
}
```